# Do you use the past tense in a subordinate clause in past subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctives, sequence-of-tenses, backshifting

- I wish I had a robot which helps me do my homework.
- I wish I had a robot which helped me do my homework.

Which sentence makes more sense?  Does the tense in the subordinate clause need to agree with the tense of the main clause?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The verb "help" is part of the "wish", so it too must be shifted to the past. Your second sentence is correct

Answer (score 0):

Attributive clauses don't require usage of sequence of tenses so the first one is correct in my opinion